# Excel 2019 opens any document in Read-Only mode on a terminal server

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have a terminal server (Server 2012 R2) used by ~10 people.

When any user (including Administrator) opens an Excel  file (xls / xlsx), it will open in read-only mode. This could be a file within a share that has full permissions for all users, or you could create a new Excel file on the desktop, open it, and immediately it is read only. Right clicking on the file and opening Properties will show that "Read only" is not checked. Users can open these files, edit them and save them to a new location without issue,

We've tried the following:

- Set it to read only, and then changed it back, still opened in read only
- Checked hidden files for lock files, there are none
- Opening multiple different Excel files from multiple locations (file server / local directories)
- Checked share permissions, not the issue
- Checked open files on the file server, the files weren't locked
- Tested Word and Powerpoint files, the issue doesn't apply to these
- Asked all users to close Office applications, and checked for stuck processes, there were none
- Asked all uses to sign out, then performed an online repair this didn't help
- Restarted the server, still same issue.
- Checked Excel Trust Centre and ensured there are no blocks on any files
- Checked Event Viewer - No related errors reported.

[image: Read only not set]
[image: Once opened, it opens in read only mode]
[image: When saving, this message appears]

We're at a bit of a dead end, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Sage was updated on the server recently, and I've just got a DLL missing error when launching Sage which points to `C:\Windows\SysWow64\sgxladdin.dll` which is a Sage Excel reporting module. So this is certainly related.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be caused by Sage Accounts 27.1 which adds a plugin to Excel, but doesn't actually include the file in the installer it seems.

Removing the plugin from Excel fixed the issue.